# Effect of randomization of order of task complexity

Tags: experiment-design, random-allocation

I was conducting an experiment where participants performed a series of tasks; however, these tasks were in random order. Which test should I use in order to confirm (or deny) that randomization of tasks didn't influence the results?

---

there were two groups of participants: one used tool 1 and the other tool 2. Then, they performed 10 tasks: 5 tasks were complex and 5 were simple. Participants received this order randomly. E.g.: participant 1 used "tool 2" and performed complex tasks first and simple tasks afterwards. Participant 2 used "tool 2" and performed simple tasks first and complex afterwards. Participant 3 used "tool 1" and performed simple tasks first, then complex etc. So basically I have four groups: tool 1 - simple tasks first; tool 1 - complex tasks first; tool 2 - simple tasks first; tool 2 - complex tasks first. I want to prove that tool 1 is significantly better than tool 2, to this end I used non-parametric tests and the results were promising. However, I am afraid that the randomization of complex and simple tasks (which group got which first?) influenced the results. I want to test if this is the case.

Comment: Compared to what? It's not quite clear what influence you're looking at. Were all participants doing the tasks in the same random order, or was each one subject to a different order?

Comment: One group used tool 1 and performed  10 tasks in random order. Other group used tool 2 and performed the same tasks in random order as well. Data is not normally distributed! How should i test that the randomization of tasks didn't influence the results? Or if it did, that's fine as well, but how to test that?

Comment: I used nonparametric test and there were significant differences between the tools - i just want to figure out if this is due randomization or tool in use

Comment: I understood that the tasks were the same in both cases. I am asking about the meaning of the phrase "in random order". Was the order randomized once, being the *same* for everyone or was it randomized for each participant?

Comment: The text belongs in your *question*. I have converted your information to an edit. So rather than the ordering of all the tasks the concern is simply over whether "simple first" vs "complex first" had an influence on the outcome?

Comment: Yes, precisely!